# How to handle touch event on UILabel as subview of UITableViewCell?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

My app has a custom `UITableView`. In the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method of its `UIViewController` I am instantiating custom `UITableViewCell` objects that contain multiple custom UILabels (actually a sub-class of `OHAttributedLabel`) as subviews of the content view.

I have tried setting `userInteractionEnabled = YES` on the label, then adding touch events in the view controller, but that isn't working.

Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is not working? Did you check if you got the right view in your touches routine?

Comment: There is nothing to check because the touches methods are never hit.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
      UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
      if (CGRectContainsPoint([self.site frame], [touch locationInView:self.view])){
       //do whatever you want
     }
}
```

Or

```
UILabel *label = =[UILabel alloc]init];
label.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture =
[[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(labelTap)]     autorelease];
[label addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

Comment: For your first suggestion... I added touchesBegan and touchesEnded events to both my UILabel subclass and also to the parent view controller, but the code is never hit when I touch a label (the property userInteractionEnabled is set to YES on my custom label).  I'm not sure what I am missing.

Comment: @Bama91 I do not know why touches event is not calling i think some thing worng you did.Okay any way did you try my second suggestion? Instead of UILabel *label = =[UILabel alloc]init]; you need to create with your custom class label and add gesture recognizer.

Comment: My bad.  A few months back while testing I had set "userInteractionEnabled = NO" in the initWithStyle method of the parent UITableViewCell.  After commenting that out, the touch events are working as expected.  Also, I found that the OHAttributedLabel is already handling touch events so I needed to be aware of that in my subclass.

Comment: hahahaha @Bama91, no matters it happens sometime, that is why i was wondering if everything is working then where is wrong. any good its working now.

Answer (score 1):

A UILabel isn't a UIControl so you won't get events on UIControlEventTouchUpInside or similar. Why not use a button instead? You can make it look exactly like a label.

Regardless you will probably need to set addTarget:action:forControlEvents: and tag on the UIButton in your cellForRowAtIndexPath: method. In that method, detect which cell's button was tapped by examining the tag value.

If you must use UILabel then you need to subclass it and intercept the touchesBegan/touchesEnded methods (inherited from UIResponder) to detect UIControlEventTouchUpInside yourself.

Comment: I'm using a subclass of OHAttributedLabel which itself is a subclass of UILabel and adds attributed text capability.  As mentioned in my comment above, the touchesBegan and touchesEnded methods added to my subclass are never hit when the label is touched.

Answer (score 1):

Problem in OHAttributedLabel. This label also handles tap on links. So for handle tap on any point of label (not just link) you must

```
self.textLabel.onlyCatchTouchesOnLinks = NO;
```

Where self.textLabel is your OHAttributedLabel. 
And don't forget of userInteractionEnabled.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is the same problem but... I added a label and could not get it to recognize a touch, I eventually realised that it was because I was adding it as a subview, but its frame was outside its parent's frame, hence the touch heirarchy broke

Answer (score 0):

I just had the problem with using static table cells for a settings table where I wanted the whole cell to trigger the first responder for the cell's textfield.

I ended up adding a transparent (custom, blank title) button behind the label (touch disabled) and textfield after not getting any touches using gesture recognizers. I think it should work in a more elegant way, but it solved the task for now and that limited purpose. (and you can just drag connect from the button's default action)

Bit ugly. Then again, it just describes the area behind the text field reacting to touch. Which was the intention after all. So maybe its just not that fancy.

Will keep it until I find the reason for the recognizers not firing.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `TTTAttributedLabel` to  instead it. it's very easy.
when you initial the  UITableViewCell,you can delegate:TTTAttributedLabelDelegate
like :

```
@interface MyTableViewCell : UITableViewCell<TTTAttributedLabelDelegate>{
    UILabel *nameLabel;
    TTTAttributedLabel *valueLabel;
}
```

when you initial ,you could add link to label :

```
 [valueLabel addLinkToPhoneNumber:valueStr withRange:NSMakeRange(0, valueStr.length)];
```

so,you could do anything you want:

```
- (void)attributedLabel:(TTTAttributedLabel *)label didSelectLinkWithPhoneNumber:(NSString *)phoneNumber{
   //do anything you want.

}
```